# Angular Observable HttpInterceptor ForkJoin Not Working

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, fork-join

I have seen multiple people mentioning issues about this but didn't find any solution for it.
I made a `HttpInterceptor` to add the token to my requests. Since I am using Firebase for authentication, retrieving the token requires an observable. Everything works fine and the token gets added but it doesn't work if I combine multiple requests with `forkJoin`.

**HttpInterceptor**:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.idToken.pipe(
        mergeMap((token: any) => {
            if (token) {
                request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
            }
            return next.handle(request);
        })
    );
}
```

**Some service**:

```
forkJoin(
    this._dataService1.fetch(),
    this._dataService2.fetch(),
).subscribe(
    ([dataService1Data, dataService1Data]) => {
        alert("Completed");  // <-------- This line of code is never reached
    }
)
```

Unfortunately, the line above in code is never reached, even though I see both of the requests completing successfully in the network tab. Could someone please give me a solution? (Both of the fetch methods from above fire an Http GET request.)

**Edit**:

```
this._dataService1.fetch().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
this._dataService2.fetch().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The above code works perfectly fine. As I mentioned it does work for individual request but not for `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forkJoin` only emits when the Observable complete. However, your `Observable` interceptor never completes. Add `take(1)` operator to your interceptor:

```js
return this.auth.idToken.pipe(
        take(1),
        mergeMap((token: any) => {
            if (token) {
                request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
            }
            return next.handle(request);
        })
    );
```

Comment: I am getting an error message saying „Argument of type ‚1‘ is not assignable to Parameter of type ‚List<unknown>‘“

Comment: You are not using the correct `take` rxjs operator. Check your import, it should be: `import {take} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works! I imported the wrong operator by accident. Could you explain to me why I need the `take(1)` though and it the observable never completes?

Comment: Your `idToken` must be a stream `Observable` which never ends. So `mergeMap` operator will send a request for EACH value of the `token` ==> You could send the same request 10 times if you emits 10 values from `idToken`. Your base `Observable` idToken never ends ==> the interceptor never ends. Using `take(1)` means: wait for the first value of token, then unsubscribe from the base `Observable`, so the interceptor Observable complete when getting first request response.

Answer (score 2):

The observables need to complete for the `forkJoin` to emit. If the observables are streams, you could use RxJS [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/combineLatest) and pipe in a [`take(1)`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take). Try the following

```js
combineLatest(
  this._dataService1.fetch(),
  this._dataService2.fetch(),
).pipe(
  take(1)
).subscribe(
  ([dataService1Data, dataService1Data]) => {
    alert("Completed");  // <-------- This line of code is never reached
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works!! There is so many operators I don’t get anything anymore. What does the take(1) do? And how do I know if my observables are streams or not?

Comment: `take()` operator listens to specific number of notifications and completes. So `take(1)` listens to only one emission and completes. About streams, observables are streams by default. Some implementations emit only one notification and complete, like the Angular HttpClient observables.