# RxJs get comments and authors

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some difficulties retrieving a comments list with they authors.

here my code

```
# list-component.ts
comments: Comment[];

constructor(private commentsService: CommentsService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commentsService.getAllWithCustomer().subscribe((comments) => {
      this.comments = comments;
      console.log('test'); // <- this never printed
    });
}
```

```
# comments-service.ts
public getAll(queryParams?: QueryStringParameters, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<T[]> {
   return this.http.get<T[]>(this.url({queryParams}), options);
}

public getAllWithCustomer(queryParams?: QueryStringParameters, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<Comment[]> {
    return this.getAll(queryParams, options).pipe(
      switchMap((comments: Comment[]) => {
        return forkJoin(
          comments.map((comment: Comment) => {
            return this.customersService.getOne(comment.customerId).pipe(
              map((customer: Customer) => {
                comment.customer = customer;
                return comment;
              })
            );
          })
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

all calls are made, both those for the list of comments and those for their authors, but the code in the subscribe method is never executed! why? where is my fault?

p.s. if I use the getAll() method istead all works fine

edit

if I add *first()* the subscription complete

```
public getAllWithCustomer(queryParams?: QueryStringParameters, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<Comment[]> {
    return this.getAll(queryParams, options).pipe(
      switchMap((comments: Comment[]) => {
        if (comments.length > 0) {
          return forkJoin(
            comments.map((comment: Comment) => {
              return this.customersService.getOne(comment.customerId).pipe(
                map((customer: Customer) => {
                  comment.customer = customer;
                  return comment;
                }),
                first()
              );
            })
          );
        }
        return of([]);
      }),
    );
  }
```

BUT in my controller the *complete()* and the *error()* are both empty:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.commentsService.getAllWithCustomer().subscribe({
      next: (comments: Comment[]) => {
        console.log('---->', comments); // <- ok
        this.comments = comments;
      },
      error: (err) => console.log('err', err), // <- no show
      complete: () => console.log('complete') // <- no show
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do all your Observables returned by this.customersService.getOne complete? Note the following description of forkJoin: "Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last values they emitted...." - https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the operators and `forkJoin`. Try to use spread syntax in the last `map` instead: `map((customer: Customer) => ({ ...comment, customer: customer })`

Comment: @SamHerrmann in my network panel i see the request to this.customersService.getOne succesful complete with code 200 and the customer object

Comment: @MichaelD I tried but nothing change

Comment: I have follow this article https://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/ for this piece of code

Comment: Pass an error handler in the subscription to see if there is any error: `.subscribe((comments) => console.log('test'), (error) => console.log(error));`

Comment: One of the evil details of forkJoin is the treatment of empty arrays. If you pass an empty array, it doesn't emit at all but instead just completes. Maybe there are no comments?

Comment: @IngoBürk there are many Comments and for each Comment I have one Customer ...

Comment: At this point I would suggest trying to boil this down into a reproducable snippet that we can execute and debug. External requests can be replaced by fake observables etc. Chances are that the process of doing this already shows or narrows down where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

solution found:

the problem was in my interceptor.
change the token-interceptor from:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.idToken.pipe(
      mergeMap((token: any) => {
        if (token) {
          request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

to:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.auth.idToken.pipe(
      take(1),
      mergeMap((token: any) => {
        if (token) {
          request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
  }
```

so adding the `take(1)` operator as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354740/angular-observable-httpinterceptor-forkjoin-not-working) solve my issue.

I really don't understand why the interceptor never ends, but this way I'm sure it does